# Combinations of arrays' elements

Tags: java, arrays, processing, combinations, cartesian-product

I stacked with a task in Java:
I got three arrays:

```
bgArray = {"bg1","bg2"};
bdArray = {"bd1","bd2","bd3"};
hdArray = {"hd1", "hd2"};
```

And I need to process it to get one array **comboArray** that filled with all combinations from that three arrays, such as:

```
bg1, bd1, hd1
bg1, bd1, hd2
bg1, bd2, hd1
```

... and so on to the end of all 12 combinations in that case.

So I need that new **comboArray** for further purposes to get access to index of that new comboArray and the index of elements within a combination. Got ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the output array (you need to calculate its dimensions to create it)
2. Loop over all 3 arrays (triple nested loop)
3. In every loop, assign the current value of each array to a new array which you copy to the output array